# Construction of non-rhombus but still paralellogram non-square-non-rectangle non-kite via Pythagorean triplet

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

Is it possible to construct a non-rhombus but parallelogram and quadrilateral non-square, Non-rectangle by putting four 3-4-5 (Pythagorean triplet) triangles together and making the 90 degree angle not at the intersection of the two diagonals?

Comment: There's some redundancy in your description: each of non-rhombus and non-rectangle already implies non-square, and parallelogram of course implies quadrilateral.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> yes

because

> you can first put two triangles together to make a 3x4 rectangle
>  (let's say the 3-sides are horizontal and the 4-sides are vertical)
>  and then attach the other two at the sides, one each way up,
>  so that you have two horizontal sides of length 6 and two
>  neither-horizontal-nor-vertical sides of length 5.
>
> ```
>        ________
>       /|  /|  /
>      / | / | /
>     /__|/__|/
> ```